# installation issues 16.04

Tags: boot

I have downloaded the Desktop version and it shows up on the disk but when I try to reboot with CD-Rom it says nothing is available.   So I tried to do this through Virtual Box and I am getting the following error.

> The image file 'C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso' is inaccessible and is being ignored. Please select a different image file for the virtual DVD drive..
>
> Error ID: DvdOrFloppyImageInaccessible
>    Severity:     Warning

Comment: Did the download completely finish? It sounds like it is a damaged ISO.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the ISO is corrupted. Does the CRC match? It might be possible the ISO didn't finish either like Tony suggested.

I would redownload it or perhaps try the mini.iso network installer and then install Ubuntu Desktop post install with `sudo apt install -y ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: I purchased a DVD-R with 4.7 GB but it is giving me the same error.   Could it be that my computers DVD burner is out of date or a setting I need to turn off or on?

Comment: No, @April. IF the ISO is corrupt you can't do anything with it, that's the point of the answer and the comment above. You need to download it again.